# Spring and Angular - Very simple REST request

Tags: javascript, java, spring, angular

I have a simple update rest controller

```
   @PutMapping("/settings/update")
public Settings updateSettings(Settings Settings) {
    return settingsRepository.save(Settings);
}
```

So far I only used get requests and all worked. But my put request never enters the controller (i have a breakpoint), so it never updates

```
 saveSettings(settingsData) {
console.log(settingsData);
return this._http.put(RequestProperties.baseUrl + "/settings/update",settingsData, this.options);
}
```

`console.log(settingsData)` prints the updated settings object

Comment: You need to subscribe to your `saveSettings` function, see [here](https://angular.io/tutorial/toh-pt6#delete-a-hero)

Comment: i forgot the subscribe. But now I get null in all fields in my controller

Comment: What does log statement in settingsData contain?

Comment: I'm now sending `JSON.stringify(settingsData)` and `console.log(JSON.stringify(settingsData));` it shows the object in a string with all fields that I changed. it's correct in the client. But in the controller I get a Settings object with all fields null

Comment: just `settingsData` doesn't work. All fields are null in the controller

Comment: Does the API work with a REST client like Postman?

Answer (score 0):

Looks like `@RequestBody Settings Settings` fixed my issue of getting null object in the controller.

**Does anyone know why?**

Comment: It is required for deserialization. To convert the JSON to java object. See https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/web.html#mvc-ann-requestbody